# Leaflet.js: Popup outside map container

Tags: javascript, css, popup, leaflet

I need open a popup window outside of map container like this:
[image: Popup over container and another div, always on top.]

Popup over map container and another div, always on top, I used a `z-index` in `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper`without success.

I used too `L.marker([14, -45]).bindPopup(content,{autoPan:false}).addTo(map);` But always show popup inside container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

A workaround would be to implement the "popup" yourself, so that it belongs to the map container *parent* rather than *inside* the map container.

You would need to implement the marker movement tracking, but with Leaflet this is rather easy:

1. use the map's [`"move"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-move) event
2. retrieve the marker current position using [`map.latLngToContainerPoint()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint)
3. move your popup using [`L.DomUtil.setTransform()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#domutil-settransform) method to apply a `translate3d` (hardware accelerated translation).

```js
map.on("move", function () {
  movePopup();
});

function movePopup() {
  var mapContainerRelativePos = map.latLngToContainerPoint(mymarker.getLatLng()),
    x = mapContainerPos.left + mapContainerRelativePos.x,
    y = mapContainerPos.top + mapContainerRelativePos.y;

  L.DomUtil.setTransform(mypopup, {x: x, y: y}, 1);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/54/

Then you are left with opening and closing the popup.

---

**Original answer**

The `L.Popup` is added within the map elements. So by default it cannot extend outside the map container.

However you could try to "extract" it (`popup.getElement()` in Leaflet 1.0) by retrieving the associated HTML Elements and appending it to an external DOM parent node, so that you are no longer bound to the map container.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried... But wasn't a good answer since a "cloned" element is possible to achieve, but it's positionning isn't good + not bounded to the map. I think the best answer is : It isn't possible, sadly. :( +1 for @ghybs

Comment: It's great! I understand better, thank you for this solution!.